# Is there possible in Lucene to find documents with nearest string?

Tags: lucene

For example i have such words in index:

```
abcde
adeb
bbcdefsdg
bdef
bfgtj
```

I want to find documents containing nearest word to given one (in the sorted list), to have something like:

`NEAREST_BOTTOM(bdeb)` that returns documents containing `bbcdefsdg` and

`NEAREST_TOP(bdeb)` that returns documents containing `bdef`

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [spell checker](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/SpellChecker) does.